# Item_Add code doesn't execute when item moved by inbox rule

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a few daily reports (Excel files) that are emailed to me. An inbox rule moves the email to an Outlook folder titled "Daily Reports".

When the email is moved into the folder by the rule, I would like the attachments to be automatically saved to a folder and organized by date. Something like: C:\Desktop\ReportName\2019\11-2019\11-05-2019 Report Name.xlsx

I have a couple of issues.

1. The code doesn't run when the rule moves the email, only when I manually move the email.
2. It creates the new directories and saves the first email's attachment however additional emails give a path/access error referencing

```vb
MkDir ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\Outlook Test Folder\" & Format(Date, "YYYY"))
```

```vb
Private WithEvents olItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Daily Reports").Items
    Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub olItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Atts As Attachments
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim attName As String
 
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        Set NewMail = Item
    End If
       
    If Dir("C:\Users\username\Desktop\Outlook Test Folder\" & Format(Date, "YYYY"), vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\Outlook Test Folder\" & Format(Date, "YYYY"))
    End If

    If Dir("C:\Users\username\Desktop\Outlook Test Folder\" & Format(Date, "YYYY" & "\" & Format(Date, "MM-YYYY")), vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\Outlook Test Folder\" & Format(Date, "YYYY") & "\" & Format(Date, "MM-YYYY"))
    End If
   
    If InStr(LCase(Item.Subject), "daily applications was executed at") > 0 Then
       strPath = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Outlook Test Folder\" & Format(Date, "YYYY") & "\" & Format(Date, "MM-YYYY")
       attName = " Daily Applications.Xlsx"
    ElseIf InStr(LCase(Item.Subject), "dailyopenedcalls was executed at") > 0 Then
            strPath = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Outlook Test Folder\" & Format(Date, "YYYY") & "\" & Format(Date, "MM-YYYY")
            attName = " Daily Opened Calls.Xlsx"
    End If

    Set Atts = Item.Attachments

    If Atts.Count > 0 Then
        For Each Att In Atts
            If InStr(LCase(Att.FileName), ".xlsx") > 0 Then
                Att.SaveAsFile strPath & "\" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & attName
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. The code doesn't run when the rule moves the email only when I manually move the email.

If multiple items are moved to a folder, the `ItemAdd` event may not be fired. This is a known issue in Outlook.

Another possible cause is that an Outlook rule is run before `Application_Startup`.

> 2. It creates the new directories just fine and saves the first emails attachment however additional emails gives a path/access error

Make sure you use symbols allowed in the path or files. I'd suggest trying to create the same path manually to make only allowed symbols were used in the path.

Comment: Eugene, 1. The reports come it at completely different times it should only be moving one item at a time. That is good to know though -- is there a work around for this ? 2. I tried hard coding it just now -- same issue. Though since the directory already exists that line shouldn't even be running ?

Comment: As a workaround, you may use a timer for checking the number of items and processing new ones.

Comment: Solved: I was missing a closing paren in my if statement causing the path issue. Item add doesn't seem to trigger when rules are manually run but it does work when it runs automatically.